# Appendices merged into the last "part"

Tags: appendices, parts

I'm writing my Thesis using TeXnicCentre 2.02 and MiKTeX 2.9.
I found a small issue that I can't fix...

I'm using some **parts** in the document, and it happens that the **appendices** are inside the last part. I've tried to use `\backmatter` without success. Can you give me a piece of advice?

A part of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright,twoside]{toptesi}
...
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
...

%% Document Parts %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\include{Cpt_0}
\include{Cpt_1}
\part{Part 1}
... some chapters ...
\part{Part 2}
\include{Cpt_2}
\include{Cpt_3}

\appendix
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc

\include{App_1}
\include{App_2}
\include{App_3}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course the `\appendix` is merged into the last part, since a `\part` command has no *bracketing* or a definite end. You can use `appendix` itself as part

Comment: By the way: Your document is not compilable, as it misses the content of the included chapters and sections, as well as `\usepackage{biblatex}`, for example

Comment: Sorry, since i needed really a lot of packages i just copied the code relative to the issue forgotting the `\usepackage{biblatex}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A suggestion for a solution: Use the Appendix as a part to get the structuring consistent.

I assumed, that `\include{App_1}` etc. contain `\chapter` commands.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright,twoside]{toptesi}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{nameref}

%% Document Parts %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents%

%\include{Cpt_0}
%\include{Cpt_1}
\part{Part 1}
... some chapters ...
\part{Part 2}
%\include{Cpt_2}
%\include{Cpt_3}


\setcounter{chapter}{0}%
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}%  Letters as 'counters'
\part{\appendixname}

\chapter{First Appendix}
\chapter{Second Appendix}
\chapter{Third Appendix}

%\include{App_1}
%\include{App_2}
%\include{App_3}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! the assumption was right... all the `\include{...}` call an external file that begins with `\chapter{...}`.

Comment: @Albert: Now, is this some agreeable solution for you? ;-)

Comment: i'm trying to modify it just a bit, avoiding the numbering for the appendices part... but it's quite near to THE solution :)

Comment: No III as Appendix number? `\part*{\appendixname}` ;-)

Comment: Now it works quite well, in the "outline" of the project the appendices are listed properly, but non in the PDF bookmarks...

Comment: \part*{} etc. does not write to the toc and generates no bookmarks

Comment: Not to be nitpicking, but the plural form of 'appendix' would be 'appendices'. Otherwise nice solution.

Comment: @Stenskjaer: I left it to the class to provide the plural form ;-) ... I know, it's appendices. But thanks

Comment: @Albert: Why did you not say anything about bookmarks? I would have provided another solution

Comment: @ Stenskjaer well... I think that it's just the "class default" Italian singular form... :)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm sorry.. it's something that came into my mind just later :)

Answer (score 3):

I found another possible solution:

```
\usepackage{bookmark}

...

\bookmarksetupnext{level=-1}
\appendix
\addappheadtotoc
\appendixpage

\include{Appendice_A}
\include{Appendice_B}
\include{Appendice_C}
```

Using this it's working properly both in toc and in bookmarks.